# HP dl360p G8 writes/latency with SSDs in raid very poor

Tags: raid, performance, hp, hp-proliant

I have a DL360P g8 server with a HPE p420i raid controller (2gb cache).
We have noticed that writes to the SSDs via raid are incredibly slow.
The drives in question I have in the arrays are:

```
Volume 1 - RAID6
  * 6 x Intel 545s 120GB SSD SATA
Volume 2 - RAID0
  * 2 x Western Digital WD Black 1TB WD10JPLX SATA
```

We have noticed that when copying from the SSD volume to the HDD volume, everything moves [about as quick as you'd expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGDBs.png).

However, copying in the opposite direction (HDD TO SSD) [the speed is terrible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf4Cw.png)

I am having trouble determining the reason for the problem, as well as a solution.

Extra things to note:

```
  * OS: ESXI 6.7 / hpe
  * All disks are brand new (note: consumer grade, not enterprise)
  * The disks are SATA rather than SAS, however I cannot find anything to explain why SATA SSDs would be as slow as they are.
  * The disk activity ring does not light up for the SSDs, however they do for the HDDs. (maybe related somehow???)
```

Things we've tried:

```
  * Installing ESXI 6.7 base
  * Installing ESXI 6.7 hpe
  * Disabling SSD Smart Path
  * Copying files with a debian live-USB
  * Updating firmwares with HP SPP gen 8.1
```

Things we've not tried:

```
  * SAS SSDs (dont have any)
  * Enabling the physical drive write cache state (that will only speed up until the 2gb buffer is full, correct?)
```

I suspect their may be some incompatibilities with the SSDs, however im unable to locate any supporting documentation to back this up,

If anything in this question does not sound quite right please feel free to point out and correct my misconceptions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

RAID-6 is a bottleneck because all writes are limited by the performance of a single drive and have a write penalty on the random or even sequential block though.
Additionally, the idea to test the performance of the datastore by simply copy and paste is not an accurate approach of benchmarking. Deploy a VM on top of the datastore with eager zeroed provisioned VMDK and test the performance using fio or diskspd. Moreover, while copying from HDD to SSD the operation is read-write which means that data is read from the HDD with the maximum performance.

Also, check this article from Microsoft - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/08/18/using-file-copy-to-measure-storage-performance-why-its-not-a-good-idea-and-what-you-should-do-instead/

Comment: I understand that copy is not a good representation of real workload as its results are rather idealistic. The point is that even in 'best case' the performance is bad.

Further thing to note is that the disks are already eager zeroed, and (in previous experience) raid6 with SSDs will generally never be as slow as whats in the images in the question.

Another thing to note is that WD blacks are not limited to 26mb reads ESPECIALLY in raid0.